# How to install python black tool in python2.7

Tags: python

I need to test `black` check in travis.yml file which is having python2.7 version how to install black in that?

```
language: python
python:
- '2.7'
install:
- pip install black
```

Comment: black requires Python 3.6 or greater. https://pypi.org/project/black/18.3a0/

Comment: Black requires python 3.6.0+ but you can format python 2 code with it. Install it in python 3 then run `black path/to/py2/file.py`. On travis use python 3.6 then you can test your code formatting. If you have to run tests for your project too you will have to create multiple jobs on travis with different python version, for testing back and normal tests.

Answer (score 3):

Black requires Python 3.6+ and you may want to look at [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/) as it is capable of creating a python3 virtual environment *just* for black.

Answer (score 1):

```
pip3 install --user black[python2]
```

With `python2` option `black` will check py2 code correctly, but for running black you need py3

Comment: Latest version of black no longer support [python2].  Pin to an earlier version using  `python -m pip install --user black[python2]==21.12b0`.  Note: I use Python 3.9 as 3.11 won't install correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
pip install black
```

> Black can be installed by running pip install black. It requires
>   Python 3.6.0+ to run but you can reformat Python 2 code with it, too.

Ref: https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation_and_usage.html

Based on this topic (https://github.com/psf/black/issues/439) Black requires python 3.6 to run.

Try `pip3 install black` if python3 and pip3 are installed.

Comment: My code is implemented under python2.7 so in travis I need to specify python2.7 version but I need to test the code with `black` for that How should I install black under python2.7.